# Table for model not found in datasource default

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I am creating a cakephp 2.x application. Midway through development, I suddenly found myself with a "table not found" error.

```
Missing Database Table

Error: Table blocked for model Parental was not found in datasource default.

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create project\View\Errors\missing_table
```

I checked my database and the associated table was actually there.

Next, I try to debug the Model. The model can access the table. The error about cakephp unable to find the datatable persists.

This is what I get when I debug the model:

```
\project\Controller\ParentalsController.php (line 5) 
object(Parental) {
    useTable => 'blocked'
    useDbConfig => 'default'
    id => null
    data => array()
    schemaName => null
    table => 'blocked'
    primaryKey => 'id'
    validate => array()
    validationErrors => array()
    validationDomain => null
    name => 'Parental'
    alias => 'Parental'
    tableToModel => array(
        'blocked' => 'Parental'
    )
    cacheQueries => false
    belongsTo => array()
    hasOne => array()
    hasMany => array()
    hasAndBelongsToMany => array()
    actsAs => null
    Behaviors => object(BehaviorCollection) {
        modelName => 'Parental'
        defaultPriority => (int) 10
    }
    whitelist => array()
    cacheSources => true
    findQueryType => null
    recursive => (int) 1
    order => null
    virtualFields => array()
    __backAssociation => array()
    __backInnerAssociation => array()
    __backOriginalAssociation => array()
    __backContainableAssociation => array()
    findMethods => array(
        'all' => true,
        'first' => true,
        'count' => true,
        'neighbors' => true,
        'list' => true,
        'threaded' => true
    )
}
```

I have also tried the following creating new table instead for the model to use. The model can access the new table, but CakePHP still cannot detect these new tables.

Please advise.

Comment: enable debug, show some specific error messages and details.

Comment: What is the exact error ?

Comment: @Charmie I have this issue before and I have edited your question to make it more concise. I have also provided a solution for you. Given that my answer has been up-voted at least twice and a comment saying my answer has saved their lives, I suggest you give my answer a try as well. If it works for you, do mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found this question when I was googling.

I had a similar issue.

I kept being prompted that I do not have a particular table when it was obviously there and I was following the conventions in naming the table as plural form.

I even cleared the cake cached files several times to no avail.

Then I changed the debug mode from 0 to 2. Suddenly the error was gone.

Then I changed the debug mode from 2 back to 0. The error was still gone.

This is a weird behavior. And I am not sure exactly how to duplicate it. I am writing this down in case somebody else faced the same issue as me.

**UPDATE:**
I have realized that for one of my apps that frequently has this problem, somehow the jenkins tasks causes some files in tmp/cache/persistent to have files in the wrong user:group.

I have corrected this yesterday. As of now, this problem has yet to appear. If the problem did not occur after another 10 days or so, I will declare that the problem is because the tmp files are not in the right permissions or user:group ownership.

Comment: Saved my life. Same weird behavior here. =\

Comment: sorry i was not able to get back here... but hey, this was the one suggested to me by my friend and it actually worked way back before  :) ... for future references of others, kimsia's answer actually works  :)

Comment: @Charmie No problems. If I found a reason to explain why this happens or a solution that solves this, I will update the answer as well.

Comment: Switching debug to 2 will allow all the model cache files to be regenerated.

Comment: @DavidYell I ran the ClearCache.clear_cache by Ceeram but that did not work. Is teh ClearCache different from regenerate the model cache files? If so, is there a way to write a library code to do that? I would like to trigger the regeneration of model cache files through either a controller action or shell.

Comment: The ClearCache plugin should work, but I find that sometimes it just doesn't work. Could be a file permissions thing. Perhaps try setting `'mask' => 0666` on your cache configuration.

Comment: Yep, like the yellow box in this section, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-class

Comment: the yellow boxes actually did not use the mask explicitly

Comment: @DavidYell I managed to trigger a situation where I have a need to change the core.php debug mode. I tried the mask and run the ClearCache. It failed. The changing of the debug mode in core.php worked.

Comment: `I even cleared the cake cached files several times to no avail.` If that doesn't fix the problem but changing debug does - then the  cache was not cleared previously at all =) (In context, all that setting debug to 2 does is expire the cache).

Comment: @AD7six I am using Ceeram's ClearCache plugin. Looks like it doesn't always work. Is there a way I can expire the cache using Shell Command?

Comment: `rm tmp/cache/*/*` - most likely you have permission problems (i.e. a tmp file created by a user that you can't delete) - check what the plugin does/did, I'm quite sure it does what it's supposed to do but it can't fix permission problems.

Comment: @AD7six I use `rm tmp/cache/*/*` instead. But it did not work. Still have to rely on changing the debug mdoe in core.php

Comment: Then there's something significant you're not saying or missing. The schema for a model is stored in cache - if you're using file cache that means it's a file under tmp. If there is no file, there is no cached result. I suggest taking a closer look at your cache settings.

Comment: @AD7six this is my settings. I have redacted the cipherseed and hash salt https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/7230130

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40242/discussion-between-kimsia-and-ad7six)

Comment: After trying so many approaches, I did this. I knew this approach too would not work for me, but surprisingly, it got me through. My smile spread ear to ear. You helped only after so many hours!

Answer (score 0):

For those that have this similar problem:

I have respected cake's conventions too but it was still unable to find that table.
I tried the method with 'debug 2/0' with no success too.

The 'magic' happened when I loaded another model that I created - only that one first, and then both of them. This method worked for me.